# Views Exposed Filters - position each filter independently

Tags: views

I am working on a drupal 7 project and have a view (v3) over 6,000 product items with 4 exposed filters.  This all works fine - I can put the "filter form" in a block - that is fine.

But I can't figure out how to separate out the individual filter drop downs for nicer positioning.  Say I want two dropdowns on the top of the result area and 2 with the apply button stacked on the left...

Is my only option to play with absolute positioning in the css?

Answer (score 8):

you can add more functionalities to Exposed Filters forms, or control his style/layout, touching template views-exposed-form.tpl.php. try this resource http://drupal.org/node/320992 or this http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/drupal-theme-the-exposed-filter-in-views/ to see guides about how to implement it.